# ¿Cómo remuevo mensajes de bash de mi terminal?

Tags: bash, terminal

Me aparecen estos mensajes en mi terminal cada que la abro, no importa si reinicio la computadora, aparece y me resulta molesto. ¿Alguien sabe como deshacerme de ello?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando Elementary OS.

Comment: Pues arreglando el error de sintaxis que te indica

Comment: Abre el archivo `.bashrc` que está en `/home/miren/`  con algún editor y elimina el error quitando `esace` de `export`. Guarda los cambios y ejecuta `source .bashrc` o reinicia.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez, eso resuelve parcialmente el problema, ahora me aparece lo siguiente: bash: /home/miren/.bashrc: línea 171: error sintáctico: no se esperaba el final del fichero. Voy a dejarl, el archivo bashrc completo, en la pregunta a ver si tu ves el error.

Comment: @mirii99 pon la línea 171 que es la que tiene el error.

Comment: Justo esa es la 171, pero ya encontre el error, no cerre un case, es decir olvide un esac. Muchas gracias. (:

Comment: unexpected end of file error (error sintáctico: no se esperaba el final del fichero) normalmente sale al olvidar poner un esac,fi, o done.